# How to extract specific words and separate them by commas?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to separate text from cells:

A1 = `Bats, Cats, Mats, Rats E`

A2 = `Bats, Pattern, Rats W`

A3 = `Cats, Mats`

A4 = `Pattern`

A5 = `Mats`

I want to remove Pattern and Mats from the rows and extract rest of the text separated by comma in one row in google sheet.

Like D1 = `Bats, Cats, Rats E`

D2= `Bats, Rats W`

D3 = `Cats`

D4 = `""`

D5 = `""`

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell `D1`:

`=arrayformula( regexreplace( regexreplace( regexreplace(A1:A5, "(Pattern|Mats)", ""), ", , ", ", " ), "^, |, $", "" ) )`

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).